# Can I consider these equations as Sturm-Liouville problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I have two ODE's and I want to solve it but I am not confident that can I consider it to Sturm-Liouville type? if I can then what will be the general solution for these equations.
\begin{aligned}
F'(X) + F(X)\, \lambda &= 0 \\
G''(Y) + \frac{1}{2}\left(Y-Y^2\right) G(Y)\, \lambda &= 0
\end{aligned}
These equations come from the PDE $$\partial_X\theta - \frac{2}{Y-Y^2} \partial_{YY}\theta = 0$$
where the separation of variables $\theta(X,Y) = F(X)\, G(Y)$ has been assumed. The boundary conditions are $\theta(X,0) = 0$ and $\partial_Y\theta(X,1) = 0$ for $X\geq 0$. The initial condition is $\theta(0,Y)=1$ for $0<Y<1$.

Comment: they come from PDE \begin{aligned}
\theta' \left(X\right) - 2/ \left(Y-Y^2\right) \theta'' &= 0

Comment: Thanks@Harry49 for your response. I tried to formulate the second equation according to Sturm-Liouville type but could not get the answer. First one is the easier one but what will be the general solution of two equations? How can I find the eigenvalue?

Comment: Thanks@Harry49 the boundary conditions for this problem are \theta[0]=0 \theta'[1]=0 and initially at X=0, theta =1.So how can I find my eigenfunctions from this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first equation is first-order, so it is not a [Sturm-Liouville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) problem. The solution is $F(X) = a_1 e^{-\lambda X}$.

The second one is a Sturm-Liouville problem over the domain where $Y(1−Y)$ is positive, i.e. $Y\in [0,1]$. Computer algebra gives
$$
G(Y)=c_1\, D_{(\sqrt{2\lambda}−8)/16}\left(\frac{(2Y−1)\lambda^{1/4}}{2^{3/4}}\right) + c_2\, D_{−(\sqrt{2\lambda}+8)/16}\left(\text{i}\frac{(2Y−1)\lambda^{1/4}}{2^{3/4}}\right)
$$
where $D_n(z)$ is the [parabolic cylinder function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderFunction.html).

The initial condition gives $a_1G(Y) = 1$. The BCs give $a_1e^{-\lambda X} G(0) = 0$ and $a_1e^{-\lambda X} G'(1) = 0$. It seems hard to solve it, but this is another problem.

Comment: thanks, Harry but I am looking for more explanation on this problem. Now, I have two solutions for two equations so how can I find eigenvalue, eigenfunction and general solution?.

Comment: Thanks, Harry for your valuable contribution. I will ask another question.