# what will be the eigenvalues and eigen functions for these equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I solved my PDE $\partial_X\theta - \frac{2}{Y(1-Y)}\partial_{YY}\theta = 0$ by using separation of variables (cf. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2899472/418542)). I got two solutions $F(X)$ and $G(Y)$ where $\theta(X,Y) = F(X)\, G(Y)$. Now, I want to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of this Sturm-Liouville problem. How can i get the general solution for this?

$F(X) = a_1 e^{-\lambda X}$

$G(Y)=c_1\, D_{(\sqrt{2\lambda}−8)/16}\left(\frac{(2Y−1)\lambda^{1/4}}{2^{3/4}}\right) + c_2\, D_{−(\sqrt{2\lambda}+8)/16}\left(\text{i}\frac{(2Y−1)\lambda^{1/4}}{2^{3/4}}\right)$

Here, $D_n(z)$ is the [parabolic cylinder function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderFunction.html).
The boundary conditions are $\theta(X,0) = 0$ and $\partial_Y\theta(X,1) = 0$ for $X\geq 0$. The initial condition is $\theta(0,Y)=1$.

Comment: Could be helpful to show the original PDE as well...

Comment: I have no idea what $D$ is, or why it is subscripted with a function of $\lambda$. However, I would say that you need to solve $G(0)=0=G'(1)$ for discrete values of $\lambda$.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 the PDE \partial_X\theta - \frac{2}{Y-Y^2} \partial_{YY}\theta = 0  where the separation of variables \theta(X,Y) = F(X)\, G(Y) has been assumed.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts D is represnting the Parabolic Cylinder Function.